# C++ Branch prediction algorithm comparison?

Tags: c++

There are 2 possible techniques shown below which do the same task.
I would like to know if there will be any performance difference between the two.
I think the first technique will suffer due to branch prediction as contents of `A` are random.

Technique 1:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define SIZE 1000000
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    private:
        bool flag;
    public:
        void setFlag(bool f) {flag = f;}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    int *A = new int[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        A[i] = (unsigned int)rand();

    time_t mytime1;
    time_t mytime2;
    time(&mytime1);

    for(int test = 0; test < 5000; test++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
             if(A[i] > 100)
                obj.setFlag(true);
             else
                obj.setFlag(false);
        }
    }

    time(&mytime2);
    cout << asctime(localtime(&mytime1)) << endl;
    cout << asctime(localtime(&mytime2)) << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
Sat May 03 20:08:07 2014

Sat May 03 20:08:32 2014
i.e. Time taken = 25sec
```

Technique 2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define SIZE 1000000
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    private:
        bool flag;
    public:
        void setFlag(bool f) {flag = f;}
};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    int *A = new int[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        A[i] = (unsigned int)rand();

    time_t mytime1;
    time_t mytime2;
    time(&mytime1);

    for(int test = 0; test < 5000; test++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
             obj.setFlag(A[i] > 100);
        }
    }

    time(&mytime2);
    cout << asctime(localtime(&mytime1)) << endl;
    cout << asctime(localtime(&mytime2)) << endl;
}
```

Result:

```
Sat May 03 20:08:42 2014

Sat May 03 20:09:10 2014
i.e. Time taken = 28sec
```

The compilation is done using MinGW 64 bt compiler with no flags.
From the results it looks like the opposite is happening.

**EDIT:**

After making the check for RAND_MAX / 2 instead of 100, I am getting the following results:

```
Technique 1: 70sec
Technique 2: 28sec
```

So it becomes clear now that Technique 2 is better than technique 1 and can be explained on the basis of branch prediction failure phenomenon.

Comment: "I would like to know". Measure.

Comment: Test it and see. If the results don't match your expectations, then ask.

Comment: First of all, see if the two even produce different machine code.

Comment: You have a good point, but the alternative creates data dependant stores, and if the data set is too big to fit lower level caches and you're bounded in load/stoer buffers - it may become slower.

Comment: With optimisations enabled I'd expect the same code from both "programs".

Comment: On x86 there is a choice between a conditional jump (if/else) and a conditional store (e.g. `setle`). Linus Torvald's post [on cmov](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html) might be interesting. You need to profile for your use case; it's possible that either one may be better on some data and worse on other kinds of data.

Comment: I have added the benchmarks above and it looks like the opposite what is expected is happening?

Comment: @Cool_Coder silly benchmarks are not cool. Both programs complete in <0.015s on my box. That's with optimizations.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by silly benchmarks? Did you benchmark with the same source code in question?

Comment: Of course. What else? I suspect the compiler is just ignoring the whole benchmark. Is the result used?

Comment: Anyways. If you're really interested in branch prediction, enable PGO on your compiler and run with `valgrind --tool=cachegrind` to see which jumps are taken how much of the time

Comment: @sehe the results in the question are without any optimisation flags. If -O3 is enabled then both perform within a sec. But without optimisations enabled why is the second technique poor than the first?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Why do you care? :/

Comment: @Cool_Coder Because you made the compile gerenate suboptimal code, duh. Problem solved.

Comment: Okay, giving Cool_Coder the benefit of the doubt, maybe he/she just wants to learn, or is curious? Understanding why exactly the non-optimized version is slower without the if-statement would surely teach something, it seems.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: You can also use performance counters to look at things like branch prediction misses. On linux it's the `perf` command.

Comment: @user3521733 I am on Windows and there is no free tool for this OS AFAIK :P

Comment: @user3521733 thern it's a codegen question, not a performance question. And all codegen is implementation defined, so would be rather an ill fit on the site, IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the fact that this isn't very interesting for practical code (especially when it dissapears with -O3), but for the sake of academic interest: In some conditions it may be better to rely on the branch predictor.

On one hand, in this particular case the branch is almost always going to be not-taken (as RAND_MAX >> 100), which is easy to predict both interms of branch resolution as well as the next IP address. Try converting the prediciton to a 50% chance and then benchmark this.

On the other hand, the second operation turns the stores done to the `obj` flag into being data-dependent with the loads from `A[i]`. These loads are going to be slow as your dataset is 1000000*sizeof(A) bytes at least (almost 4MB), meaning that it could be either in the L3 cache or the memory - either way that's quiet a few cycles per each new line (once every few accesses) - when the writes to the flag were independent, they could queue in parallel, now you have to stall them until you get the data. In Theory, the CPU should be able to "pipeline" this, since stores are performed much later than loads along the pipeline on most CPUs, but in practice you're limited by the size of the execution window, in most machines that would be ~100 I believe), so if the store of the current iteration is stalled, you won't be able to launch too far ahead the loads required for the future iterations.

In other words - you may be losing due to the fact that CPUs have a fairly decent branch prediction, but no (or hardly no) data prediction.

Comment: Yes you are correct! I did the benchmark with 50% chance and the results are as excpected. But regarding your cache miss comments I dont understand. As everything is same for both technique both will experience the same cache miss, right?

Comment: And when I enable -O3 it takes less than 1sec as against 28 sec without -O3 for the technique 2. So what optimisation is compiler doing? I Am asking so that I will use that optimum code instead in future.

Comment: @Cool_Coder, You do a simple stream of loads (`A[i]`). and stores (always to the addr of `obj.flag`). In the if-else case, these streams are unrelated (aside from branch mispredictions due to earlier loads), but in the second case - each stores' data depends on the outcome of the load of the same iteration. This adds data dependency. The CPU is usually very clever about read-after-write (and can forward the data), but in this case you really have to wait for the data, therby  forcing the stores to perform much later, and prevent the machine from "clearing" older iterations.

Comment: Let's say a memory operation taken 1000 cycles (just for the sake of argument), and each cycle can issue a load and a store. It means the store of iteration 0 can only commit in parallel to the load of iteration 1000, because the load of iteration 0 wasn't ready before that time. But your machine isn't likely to be able to hold 1000 iterations in its buffers simultaneously, you'll probably get stuck after 30-40 (depending on the CPU of course)

Answer (score 3):

With optimisations enabled the binaries are *exactly the same*, in GCC 4.8 at least: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36f4d2b533327b73).

They're different with optimisations disabled, though: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c8647e494ae7989).

This very poor attempt at a measurement suggests that the second is actually slower, though both programs run in the same duration in real terms: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13ad09665ab65c99)

> `real 0m0.052s`
>   `user 0m0.036s`
>   `sys  0m0.012s`
>
> `real 0m0.052s`
>   `user 0m0.044s`
>   `sys  0m0.004s`

To find out how they *really* differ in performance with optimisations disabled, you can benchmark properly with more runs.

Frankly, though, since it's irrelevant for your production code I wouldn't even bother.

Comment: @Tomalak I have added the benchmarks and the results are opposite of what you are getting. I have added the complete code.

Comment: @Cool_Coder: No, your result is the same as what I am getting. You shouldn't benchmark using walltime, though; benchmark using CPU time _for that process_ (which is `user` in my output above).

Comment: Sorry, yes. So why is the second technique poor than first without optimisations enabled?

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Don't know don't care ;) It is pointless to rationalise about it. Turn on optimisations and continue programming your application.

Comment: And its nice to see you back on SO. Although I miss Mooing Duck ;)

Comment: @Cool_Coder: He was last seen 11 hours ago according to his profile. Have you travelled back in time from some post-apocalyptic future?!

Comment: @Cool_Coder: Look at the generated assembly for clues as to why their is a difference in the unoptimized case. But note that you have `> 100` in one and `> 10` in the other.

Comment: @Fahad: Yeah I did. Click on the links labelled "demo" to see that.